# Putting a link to shell:startup still doesn't load a program on startup (Windows 8)

Tags: windows, windows-8

I opened `shell:startup`, copied a link to my program there, rebooted - and my program didn't start with Windows.

But, when I open `shell:startup` and double click on that link - the program starts.

Is there any switch I need to check to tell Windows 8 start programs on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open MSConfig and make sure the Normal Startup is checked

Comment: no, "selective startup" is chosen. I pick "normal startup", click "Ok", and when I go to msconfig again - it still has "selective startup" selected. any suggestions?

Comment: it's now "normal startup" but program still didn't start automatically

Comment: Interesting. It could be some registry or group policy setting. Is this a company computer or perhaps someone manage this pc for you? Antivirus or system utilities could also block it for protecting your PC.

Comment: What happen if you put simple file (not shortcut, but the file itself) inside the startup folder? Say, a text file should launch notepad opening that file.

Comment: hm.. just copied a .txt file there - and it got opened by Notepad. but a shortcut still didn't work. You think a problem can be with my program and I should try to post it in StackOVerflow?

Comment: Ah, so it's your own app? Yeah, it's SO domain, explain your app resource access (network, SQL server, service, etc) if any and if your app rely to some precondition (working directory, user rights)

Answer (score 0):

I know Winodws 8 does disable some startup items if the impact on boot is high.  You can verify if Windows or any other tool has disable this particular/all startup entries by looking up the new tab in Windows 8.

Task Maanger (Ctrl + Shift + Esc) > Start-up.  You can know if any start up has been disabled.

Comment: Did Windows 8 disable them automatically?

Comment: I remember once a dialog had come up asking what to do.  An explicit input was to be given.  But I feel, may be some setting in windows or some other software could make those decision implicit.  It is just a possibility.  Checking the status now 'enabled/disabled' can help in eliminating this as a potential issue.

Comment: Yea, setting the MSConfig to normal startup does the same thing. Windows only display the impact http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but will never automatically kill those with high impact. Why? Because every antivirus will marked with high impact, and if Microsoft killed those, say without digital signature from Microsoft declaring it as antivirus thus requiring the exemption, EU would force Microsoft to put yet another "choice screen" for antivirus